# Kotlin Arrow EffectScope.shift() implementation throws exception?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt, effect-systems

When looking at arrows documentation about [functional error handling](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/error_handling/) one of the reason listed to avoid throwing exceptions is performance cost (referencing [The hidden performance costs of instantiating Throwables](http://normanmaurer.me/blog/2013/11/09/The-hidden-performance-costs-of-instantiating-Throwables/))

So it is suggested to model errors/failures as an `Effect`.
When building an `Effect` to interrupt a computation the `shift()` method should be used (and under the hood it is also what is used to "unwrap" the effects through the `bind()` method).

Looking at the `shift()` [method implementation](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/main/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/continuations/Effect.kt#L740) seems that its magic is done...throwing an exception, meaning that not only exceptions are created when we want to signal an error, but also to "unwrap" any missing `Option`, `Left` instance of an `Either` and all the other effect types exposed by the library.

What I'm not getting is if there's some optimization done to avoid the issues with "the hidden performance costs of instantiating Throwables", or in the end they are not a real problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'm not getting is if there's some optimisation done to avoid the issues with "the hidden performance costs of instantiating Throwables", or in the end they are not a real problem?

The argumentation that this is the *biggest reason* for using typed errors on the JVM is probably an overstatement, there are better reason for using typed errors. Exceptions are not typed, so they are not tracked by the compiler. This is what we want to avoid if you care about type-safety, or purity. This will be better reflected in the documentation or 2.x.x.

Avoiding the performance penalty can be a benefit in hot-loops, but in general application programming it can probably be neglected.

However to answer your question on how this is dealt with in Kotlin, and Arrow:

In Kotlin cancellation of Coroutines works through `CancellationException`, so it's **required** to use this mechanism to correctly work in the Kotlin language. You can find more details in the [Arrow 2.x.x `Raise` design document](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/pull/2797).

It's possible to **remove the performance penalty** of exceptions. Which is also what Arrow is doing. (Except a small regression in a single version, this was be fixed in the next release).

An example of this can also be found in the official KotlinX Coroutines which applies the same technique for disabled stack traces for [`JobCancellationException`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/3788889ddfd2bcfedbff1bbca10ee56039e024a2/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Exceptions.kt#L29).